# Elements in a ROW auto placement for different sizes

Tags: html, css

i'm doing an input with tags just like in Stackoverflow

[image]

I'm trying to add tags in different sizes in a row but i cant make them fit the height of the input without pushing the input out of it own height..

I tried using a Psuedo element `:before` so it won't take up space but than i have a bigger problem with the spacing and rows adding and so on..

[image]

See how it doesnt change height when added a tag in.. it's not taking up space but its not `position: absolute` so..

this is my code: (again i dont want to use psuedo element or absolute)

```
.auto-comp-wrap
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
    position: relative
    display: block
    padding: 0 $gap-rg
    width: 100%
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem
    border-radius: $bullet
    cursor: text
    .auto-comp-item
        position: relative
        display: inline-flex
        flex-direction: row
        align-items: center
        background: none
        width: auto
        height: unset
        margin-left: 1.25rem
        @include fs-rg
        &:before
            position: absolute
            content: ''
            width: calc(100% + 1rem)
            height: 100%
            padding: 1rem 0
            top: 50%
            left: 50%
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
            border-radius: 3px
```

Comment: So show us the code you currently have and then we can suggest fixes

Comment: @RiggsFolly edit ^

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox, i made a fiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/AurScha/akoxs5gr/

```
<div class="tags-wrapper">
<div class="tag">
    tag 1
</div>
<div class="tag">
    tag 2
</div>
<div class="tag">
    tag 3
</div>
<div class="tag">
    tag 4
</div>
<input type=text class="tag-input" />
```

CSS :

```
.tags-wrapper{
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    display:flex;
    padding: 5px;
}
.tag-input{
    flex: 1;
}
.tag{
    background: red;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding:0 8px;
}
```

edit : for multiple rows https://jsfiddle.net/AurScha/akoxs5gr/30/

Comment: Seems good but the problem with using flex is when the tags reaches the with limit of the wraper and i need "new row" ..

Comment: you should look at grid display then

Comment: the problem with drid is that every column needs to be in different size, and it affects the columns in the next rows..

Comment: just edited the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AurScha/akoxs5gr/23/ still using flexbox

Comment: its better but if there is only one row the problem is with `margin-bottom` because it leaves an unwanted gap in the bottom of the container

Comment: now the problem is that you determined that size of the divs to strech and keep their auto size..